# How to get rid of the gaps when using text-align: center?

Tags: css

I noticed while using `text-align: center` that the text I'm trying to center isn't quiet centered.

Here's an example and screenshot of what I mean:

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span style="background-color: green">Digital</span> <span style="background-color: blue">World</span>
</h1>
```

[image: not quiet centered text]

You'll see the lines (green box and blue box) are perfectly centered. However, the text within the boxes are not, respectively the boxes are larger than the text itself. You can notice this at different points:

- "D" in "Digital" has space on the left side, while the "L" has almost nothing on the right side
- "W" in "World" has almost no spacing on the left side, while the "D" has a visible gap on the right side

While experimenting I found out that different letters lead to different results. Hence, my suspicion that it has to do with the font and the glyphs. I assume, that the "W" which is wider uses more available space for its glyph than the "D". Thus, I want to tell CSS to calculate sizes in a different way, I guess.

All of this resulted in me going down a rabbit hole of `font-feature-settings` and the CSS specification. As far as I understand the UA calculates the size of the text on a different basis than what I would do optically. *but I'm not sure if that's correct*

So, the questions are:

- Why are there gaps when centering text?
- How can I tell the UA to "not do gaps"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way to fix this as it's caused by the font's left and right "side bearing".

As it is from the font itself there is no way to remove or manipulate this with CSS.

You could play around with left padding's manually splitting letters/words into their own tags.

See this question for more details.
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159977/leading-space-padding-in-sans-serif-fonts

Comment: Thank you! Seems like my feeling was correct and now I know how to call it. Little bit sad that there is no solution :'(

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form an answer here of your own or delete this altogether.